# Circular references and warnings caused by forward declarations in Object C

Tags: objective-c, warnings

I have two classes that reference each other and therefore a forward declaration is required to avoid circular references.  Because of the forward declaration I get all kinds of warnings when trying to reference the class name or properties of the class that has the forward declaration.  Any suggestions?  The key constraint is I need to preserve the ability to have the classes reference each other

ClassA.h

```
#import "ClassB.h"

@interface ClassA : NSObject {
    ClassB *class_b;
}
@end
```

ClassB.h

```
@class ClassA;

@interface ClassB : NSObject {
     ClassA *class_a;

}

@end
```

ClassB.m

```
#import "ClassB.h"


@implementation ClassB

-(void)method{
}
- (id)init
{
    (self = [super init]);
    class_a = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    return self;
}


@end
```

The warning I get is as follows:

```
ClassB.m:13: warning: receiver 'ClassA' is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `ClassB.m` you need to `#import "ClassA.h"`. The `@class` forward declaration is just for the header file.

Answer (score 0):

The headers only need to know ClassA and ClassB exist and so a forward declaration works.

However in the implementation they need to know more about the other class. Thus in the implementation files you need to #import the other class. You don't have the an issue as the implementation of one class only needs to know the interface of the other,

Answer (score 0):

In headers do not use import/include but use the @class directive. It basically tells "there is a class called X defined somewhere"